# Length of args in Java

Tags: java, parameters, share, program-entry-point, args

What is the length of main's args in Java? is it dynamic? I want to pass parameters between two main methods, can I send any number of String arguments?

Comment: Args between two main threads? Are you talking about two separate Java processes?

Comment: yes, in fact I'm facing an exception, and I thought it's about args length, thank you!

Comment: I think you should post your code.

Comment: args is a String array and its length will be the number of parameters you will pass to it.

Comment: could someone explain to me why this question is down-voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this conclusions:

1. args as any arrays is static not dynamic, but it's length is determined at run-time, and this doesn't make it dynamic anyway.
2. we can `pass` (not `send`) arguments to other main method as it's just like any other method, it doesn't create a new thread.

> I was thinking that calling main method would ***run*** another
>   thread, that was just somehow stupid.

it's just executed in the memory of the caller thread, if we want to pass variables between two thread, we can use sockets

***Edit***

After nearly 20 months, here I'm back to this thread again, to correct my misconceptions about Java language.

Answer (score 0):

It is dynamic. You can send as many/few values as required.